# Smarty table even odd

Tags: php, smarty

I'm is using PHP smarty templater. I need to create even odd row highlighting.
Please, send me example how to do that.

also I have variable:

```
$smarty.foreach.product.index
```

Comment: I won't send!! What have you tried ?

Comment: Did you even try? First hit on Google seems promising: [Best way to do: first last odd even](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=48792)

Comment: Go to the nearest blackboard and start writing: "I will use google before asking question with answers everywhere". Write this 20 times, and after that go to this link: http://www.iinuu.eu/en/it-guru/how-to-create-zebra-stripes-in-table-smarty-jquery-css3

Comment: have you heard about modulo ?

Comment: thank you for answer as a comment!

Comment: Sorry, I can not use the by Google!

Comment: @user - *why* can't you use the google link? what about it didn't work? have you tried to adapt it to your needs? Also, are you aware that odd/even row colouring [can be done in pure CSS](http://philihp.com/blog/2011/css-evenodd-row-selectors-finally/); you may not even need to use Smarty for this at all (depending on the browser support you need).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For this kind of situation smarty has method called {cycle}

```
<table>
{foreach $products as $product}
<tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
   <td>{$product.name}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

The result for this will be:

```
<table>
<tr class="odd">
   <td>1st product</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
   <td>2nd product</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
   <td>3rd product</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In you stylesheet file define properties for odd and even lines like this:

```
tr.even td{background: #CCCCCC;}
tr.odd td{background: #EFEFEF;}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
{foreach key=i item=row from=$items}
<tr{if $i%2==1} bgcolor=#e4e4e4{/if}><td>{$i}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

Comment: Its best if you also include some explanation along side your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
{section name=myloop start=0 loop=10 step=1}
<tr class="{if $smarty.section.myloop.index is even}tr_even{else}tr_odd{/if}"><td>{$smarty.section.myloop.index}</td></tr>
{/section}
```

Comment: This also works with any foreach (based on Brians question): `{if $smarty.foreach.product.index is even} I'm even! {else} I'm odd! {/if}`